# why there are at most $6$ possible automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

find the  possible automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}?$

**My attempt** : Since the minimal polynomial  of $\zeta_3$  over $\mathbb{Q}$  is $ x^2 +x +1$ .So  any automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}$ must send  $\zeta_3$  to one  of the two roots  $\zeta_3 ,\zeta_3^2$

similarly  the minimal polynomial  of  $\sqrt[3] 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^3 -2 $. So any automorphism  of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}$ must send  $\sqrt[3]2$ to one  of the three root $\sqrt[3]2 , \sqrt[3]\zeta_3$ and $\sqrt[3]\zeta_3^2$

Therefore there  are at most $5$ possible automorphism  of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}$

But in **Dummit and Foote** book  it is written that   there  are at most $6$ possible automorphism  of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}$

**My confusion**: why there  are at most $6$ possible automorphism of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2, \zeta_3)/ \mathbb{Q}?$

Comment: You have a typo. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_3$ is $x^2+x+1$. Also there is a standard theorem that if $[K:F] $ is finite then $|\text {Aut} (K/F) |\leq [K:F] $ and the equality holds only if $K/F $ is Galois.

Comment: okay  @ParamanandSingh i edited

Comment: You can observe that $\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt [3]{2},\zeta_3)$ is of degree $6$ over $\mathbb {Q} $ and hence by previous comment there can be at most six automorphisms which leave the rationals fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $2 \times3$, not $2+ 3$ choices.

The two options you list (two choices in one case, three in the other) might be independent. Any of the six combinations *might* produce an automorphism, and would determine that automorphism.